# How to auto number table entries

Tags: markdown

I want to use **markdown** to maintain a structured table. I will occasionally insert some new entries into the middle of the table, and I always need to quickly get the total number of the entries. If I could automatically number the table entries, then everything is easy. But I cannot figure out how to do it.

As an **example**, I want to create a table like this

| No. | Name | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Apple | Blah |
| 2. | Banana | Blah |
| 3. | Berry | Blah |

I can quickly get the number of table entries from the last line, which is 3.

What I have **tried** in VS Code is

```
| No. | Name   | Attribute |
| --  | --     | --        |
| 1.  | Apple  | Blah      |
| 1.  | Banana | Blah      |
| 1.  | Berry  | Blah      |
```

But I got `1.`s in column `No.` of all entries.

If I insert a new entry `| 1.  | Arbutus | Blah      |` between the 1st entry and the 2nd entry, I expect to get

| No. | Name | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Apple | Blah |
| 2. | Arbutus | Blah |
| 3. | Banana | Blah |
| 4. | Berry | Blah |

Then I know the number becomes 4.

**P.S.**, I know I can do it with Excel, DB, or other programming languages, but I wonder if I can do this with lightweight markdown.